# Running a Sencha Touch application in the background on Android

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a android application using Sencha Touch with Phonegap.
It is a tracking application, so it is important for the application to keep tracking in the background.
When I run `sencha app build -run native` in my command prompt, the application runs perfectly on my phone. It is possible to go out of the application and back in again without the application starting all over again.

The problem occurs when I try to install an .apk file instead of doing it in the cmd. Then the application shuts down every time I go out of it.

How can I make it keep running in the background? What is different from building on the phone and installing the .apk?

I have search a lot of places and found some plugins ([Cordova BackgroundMode-Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) and [Build your own Background Service](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service) ), but  I can't seem to get any of them to work. I allso tried to enter `< preference name="keepRunning" value="true" />` in the config.xml file..

I hope someone can help me out with this.

-Sofia

Answer (score 0):

When you suspend an app, Javascript execution stops too.May be this plugin will helpful:
https://github.com/jocull/phonegap-backgroundjs